# regular expression - how to get ANY arrangement of characters?

Tags: java, regex, string

For this specific example, I want to do regex pattern matching in Java to find out if a string matches this pattern, where it must be:

```
<APOSTROPHE><ANY WORD WITHOUT SPACES><APOSTROPHE>
```

I have tried to set it to `"(')([\w+])(')"`, but then it won't consider any special characters like ! or %.

How do I make it so I can get 
" **'Hello!'** " 
or 
" **'Yo%#@'** "

to be recognized as a valid pattern?

Comment: Sure, you need to use `'[^\s']+'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this RegEx: `^'[\\S]+'$`

```
String pattern = "^'[\\S]+'$";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
System.out.println(patt.matcher("'Yo%#@'").matches()); // must pass
System.out.println(patt.matcher("'Hello'").matches()); // must pass
System.out.println(patt.matcher("'Hel lo'").matches()); // must fail
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For simple search between `'` symbols you can use

```
'([^']*)'
```

`[^']` includes anything that is not apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

I you want `<APOSTROPHE><ANY WORD WITHOUT SPACES><APOSTROPHE>`

Just do : `"^'[\S]*'$"` ( `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^'[\S]*'$");`)

This https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html can be useful for you and before ask in forum always search in google "myQuestion + java" and you'll surely find it

Comment: That's what I did.